# How to insert a large amount of records to the database in a short time?

Tags: sql-server, c#

I have to insert a bunch of records(*500,000*) to the database at once, using the fastest way. I've tried inserting *1,700* records at once but it took twenty minutes!! I am using `SQL-SERVER`, and `C#`.

Although the following table won't contribute to the technique for fast inserting, I decide to link it anyway so you get a better understanding about the number of fields I need to insert(duplicate it by around *500K*).

[image: The Fields]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options.  Here are the main ones that come to mind.

**SSIS** - SQL Server Integration Services: This is SQL Servers ETL tool and you can move data from pretty much any source to pretty much any destination and it can be quite fast.

**BCP** - Bulk Copy Program: This is a command line tool that comes with SQL Server.  It's very good at moving text files into SQL Server or you can export into a native format from one SQL Server and import using that same format into another SQL Server.  BCP is also very fast but a bit more limited than SSIS.

**INSERT INTO tablename SELECT fieldlist FROM othertable**: This assumes that you are moving from one SQL table to another on the same server.  This is the fastest but at 500k rows you are looking at a fairly big transaction or having to break it up like you said.

**OPENROWSET**: This is a SQL Server function that will let you pull data into a table from various formats.  It's also supposed to be fairly quick but I haven't worked with it much.

General note: Your primary key is mbr_id.  If this is something that is stored in your source data (as opposed to being an identity column) your insert will go MUCH faster if the source data is in mbr_id order.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using. NET, you can actually stream the data in *without* calling an external process. You would use Table-Valued Parameters. See my answer on StackOverflow for details and a link to another variation of this method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25815939/577765

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it faster (especially if this is an initial population of a table) see about removing indexes as well.